# Highlight upcoming/overdue calculated column dates in a training list

Tags: jquery, custom-list, calculated-column

I have a list to track customer training. Two of the trainig items are recurring; Ethics - annual and GPC Refresher - biannual (every two years). The due dates for each training requirement were created using a calculated column. I would like each cell of those calculated column dates to highlight yellow when they are 30 days out, and highlight red when they are due and past due. I am running SP2013, on-prem, and do not have Designer. I've been able to use a script editor web part to change the font color of certain words in another list that worked great, but highlighting the cell of calculated column dates is over my head. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Refer this - http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/169777/using-calculated-column-to-highlight-entire-row-in-list/169785#169785

Comment: Hope this helps too: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/172731/color-code-due-date-field-if-6-months-before-current-date

Answer (score 0):

Calculated columns are updated only when the item itself is updated, so for your indication to be always up-to-date, you'll have to use client-side tricks.

You can adapt [ViewMaster](http://www.viewmaster365.com/#/How). Start from a new calculated field with this formula:

```
="<img src=""_layouts/images/blank.gif"" onload=""console.log('ViewMaster executed on: " & [Title] & " ');"">"
```

If you're lucky then [Danny Engelman](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/32871/danny-engelman) himself will help you :)

Comment: That ViewMaster site wil get you started with JavaScript in Calculatd Columns *step-by-step* Adding color and Today calculations I answered in multiple posts here on SO: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A32871+icc+color

Comment: Thanks for the comments! Aziz, I added your formula to my list; however, nothing happened. Danny, I checked out your other posts, and can't quite figure this out. I'm not a programmer and learned how to use our basic, out-of-the-box, SharePoint through trial and error and YouTube University. I did try your 'Hello World!' button on the View Master site, and it worked, I think. A 'Click Me' button was added to every row of a list; however, when clicked, nothing happened. I think what I'm asking is too complicated for my level of knowledge.