# Calculated column output with CSR

Tags: 2013, jquery, client-side-rendering, integrate-remedy-sp2013

I have a calculated column which returns YES NO. I want to color code the entire row based on these values. Below is my code using CSR

```
**(function () {
    // Initialize the variable that stores the objects.
    var overrideCtx = {};
    overrideCtx.Templates = {};
    //OnPostRender call postRenderHandler function.
    overrideCtx.OnPostRender = postRenderHandler;

    // Register the template overrides.
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);
})();
function postRenderHandler(ctx) {
    var rows = ctx.ListData.Row;
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var CALOUTPUT = rows[i]["Start of Month"] === "YES";
      //alert(isApproved);
        if (CALOUTPUT) {
            var rowElementId = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, rows[i]);
            var tr = document.getElementById(rowElementId);
            tr.style.backgroundColor = "#ada";
        }
    }
}**
```

CALCULATED Formule

```
=IF(AND([Due Date]<TODAY(),TODAY()<[0-30days]),"YES","NO")
```

Comment: You can try this type of calculated column formula for color: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/169777/using-calculated-column-to-highlight-entire-row-in-list/169785#169785

Comment: I think Your code is not working when have a group by set for the view. I removed it and it is working. But if we want Group by then??

Comment: It's working in my list even in group by

Comment: yaa i is working now .. my page was in cache ... thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() {

   SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
     OnPostRender: function(ctx) {

       var calcColors =  {
          'Yes' : '#FFFFFF',  
          'No' : '#FF0000' 
       };

       var rows = ctx.ListData.Row;
       for (var i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
       {
          var calculatedCol = rows[i]["Start of Month"];
          var rowId = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, rows[i]);
          var row = document.getElementById(rowId); 
          row.style.backgroundColor = calcColors[calculatedCol];
        }
      }
   });
});
```

Related article to CSR :

- [INTRO TO CLIENT-SIDE RENDERING IN SHAREPOINT 2013](http://www.rbradbrook.co.uk/blog/2013/04/14/introduction-to-client-side-rendering-in-sharepoint-2013/)
- [SP 2013 Client Side Rendering: List Views](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views)

Comment: var calculatedCol is geeting undefined when i put alert??. Output of the Calculated column is not geeting using CSR

Comment: check if debugger mode if rows[i]["Start of Month"] is giving correct value. Make sure your column name is correct, even check for spaces

Comment: My column name is correct it should be display name only right??. I have added the list view webpart in a page and added the JS link over there is this correct

Comment: Use internal name

Comment: Did it worked ?

Comment: when i removed group by it worked :-) thanks Gaurrav.

Comment: welcome @sandy143

Answer (score 1):

## Your code will only work if you **Update ALL Items EVERY day**

As explained in: [How to use Today and Me in Calculated column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151144/how-to-use-today-and-me-in-calculated-column/151336#151336)

You have to do the Today comparison in the JavaScript code

I whipped this up quick, works on a standard Task List.

[image]

```
function ColorCodeDueDate(ctx) {
  var fieldname=ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.RealFieldName,
      datevalue=new Date(ctx.CurrentItem[fieldname]),
      days=GetDaysAfterToday(datevalue);
  if (!days) return 'No '+fieldname;
  if (days<5) style="background-color:red;color:white";
  if (days<-30) style="background-color:green;color:white";
  return String.format("<div style='{0}'>{1} days from {2:dd/MM/yyyy}</div>",style,days,datevalue);
}
```

Notes:

- Use the [Chrome Extension Cisar](https://365csi.nl/cisar) (by Andrei Markeev) to code CSR files.
- Should be easy to spot how to change it to your 180 days
- Do **not** hardcode internal fieldnames; this function can be applied to any DateTime field
- Try to code with only one exit point (return) in your functions; makes it a lot easier to read
- **GetDaysAfterToday()** comes from SharePoints own `sp.datetimeutil.js` library, but you might have to load it as extra JSLink first; because SP loads it **after** your CSR code executes
  (OR copy that function code into your own CSR file)
- **String.format()** comes from  SharePoints `msajaxbundle.js`; which is loaded **before** your CSR code executes

[image]

#### With the https://iCSR.github.io Library you do not have to write a function at all

If you declare the View as:

```
'MaxEndDate':{
  View : iCSR.DueDate({
                        ranges:'[msRed],0,#FFF1AD,90,[msGreen]'
                        ,rowcolor:true
                        })
}
```

You get this: (screenshot from another post)

- msRed and msGreen are [iCSR](https://iCSR.github.io) *tokens* matching the colors from the new Microsoft Planner
- iCSR adjusts the textcolor contrast for you (*on each cell, you can't set a textcolor on a TR row*)
- and more

[image]